# How to remove string part in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string **2010-2011**, I would like to get result like this **2010-11**, using php's substr() method I have tried but `substr('2010'.'-'.'2011',0,7)` not been able to get exact output, though I have tried from other posts.

Comment: Is the value always static? A regex such as `((\d{2})\d{2})-\2(\d{2})` might be useful, replace with `\1-\3`.

Comment: no it's dynamic, I have taken a sample scenario only @chris85

Comment: With substr you will need to make two calls, regex isn't usable?

Answer (score 3):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would be easier to use:

```
$str = '2010-2011';
$replaced = str_replace('-20', '-', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substr` twice, first to get first five digits and second to get last two.

```
<?php
$string = "2010-2011";

echo substr($string, 0, 5) . substr($string, -2);
```

see example: https://eval.in/578870

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expression (preg_replace) instead like so:

```
        <?php
            $string         = "2010-2011";
            $desiredString  = preg_replace("#(2010)(\-)(20)(\d{2})#", "$1$2$4", $string);

            echo $desiredString; // DISPLAYS: 2010-11;
```